# Is it fine when Scala Map accept the mutable object as a key?

Tags: scala

```
val list2=List(2,3)
val list3=ListBuffer(4,5)

list3.hashCode ==> -770945474

scala> val map2=Map((list3,list2))
val map2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int],List[Int]] = Map(ListBuffer(4, 5) -> List(2, 3))
```

If I add the element to the `list3` in future it may change the hash value of `list3`.
In Map => It will change the bucket of the value "list2"  for the key "list3".

`list3+=6`  =>  `ListBuffer(4, 5, 6)`

```
scala> map2
val res74: scala.collection.immutable.Map[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int],List[Int]] = Map(ListBuffer(4, 5, 6) -> List(2, 3))
```

Now `list3.hashCode` ===>  341479237

`map2` was already defined then how it was changing the value inside `map2` when I change the `list3`.

Comment: Because is the same object the one you are mutating. Thus, even if you pass another buffer with the same values you won't get the result, rather you need to use the very same buffer. Which usually is not a good idea.

Comment: Uhm no, it seems I am totally wrong in the last part, check [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/kSijnPxUQ82RAE1adWs96g/5). I would call this a bug to be honest; oh well mutability really hurt my head.

Comment: I don't understand what is the question here?

Comment: when I append the value in the list buffer after map2 object defined how the change was reflected inside the map2 object. here list buffer was defined as key  in the map2 object before

Comment: Because a `ListBuffer` is mutable and the map keeps a reference to it.

Comment: Assume Scala feeds ListBuffer(4,5) to the hash() function, takes the result, and uses that to find the value as  List(2,3)
 
Now when you ask Scala for the value of the key ListBuffer(4,5,6), is scala able to find the correct value. Because the hash value was changed right.

Comment: @muthukrishnan the thing is that when you create a `Map` of a single element **Scala** uses a special kind of `Map`, if you use a `HashMap` directly everything breaks in a funny way: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/kSijnPxUQ82RAE1adWs96g/7 - Conclusion, don't use mutable things as keys of a `HashMap`